# A responsive arrangement of columns I need with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have twelve social icons.

I want to be:

12 in row in desktop mode (makes 1 row)

3 for each row in tablet mode (makes 4 rows)

1 for each row for mobile size (makes 12 rows)

I have this markup:

```
<div class='container'>
   <div class='row'>

<div class='col-md-1'></div>
<div class='col-md-1'></div>
<div class='col-md-1'></div>
<div class='col-md-1'></div>

<div class='col-md-1'></div>
<div class='col-md-1'></div>
<div class='col-md-1'></div>
<div class='col-md-1'></div>

<div class='col-md-1'></div>
<div class='col-md-1'></div>
<div class='col-md-1'></div>
<div class='col-md-1'></div>

   </div>
</div>
```

But it soon becomes into twelve rows (in tablet mode).

Thanks

Comment: Hi were any of the below answers what you were looking for?

Comment: Hi. They all are correct. But I had used them before asking the above question. What I needed was a "something" which could break col-xs-* into smaller sections (more media-queries) for devices smaller than 760px. Though I utilized Javascript (instead of media-query) to add more sizes to col-xs-*

Answer (score 4):

use

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-1"></div>
```

for each div

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-1'>1</div>
        <div class='col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-1'>2</div>
        <div class='col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-1'>3</div>
        <div class='col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-1'>4</div>
        <div class='col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-1'>5</div>
        <div class='col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-1'>6</div>
        <div class='col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-1'>7</div>
        <div class='col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-1'>8</div>
        <div class='col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-1'>9</div>
        <div class='col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-1'>10</div>
        <div class='col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-1'>11</div>
        <div class='col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-1'>12</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/leighking2/bkxj7772/ (adjust width of preview to see it change)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this..

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-1">x</div>
     <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-1">x</div>
     <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-1">x</div>
     <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-1">x</div>
     <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-1">x</div>
     <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-1">x</div>
     <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-1">x</div>
     <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-1">x</div>
     <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-1">x</div>
     <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-1">x</div>
     <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-1">x</div>
     <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-1">x</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/oSLoSE9saE

Notice you don't need the `col-xs-12` since Bootstrap will stack by default on the smallest devices (phones)

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class='container'>
   <div class='row'>

<div class='col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-12'></div>
<div class='col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-12'></div>
<div class='col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-12'></div>
<div class='col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-12'></div>

<div class='col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-12'></div>
<div class='col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-12'></div>
<div class='col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-12'></div>
<div class='col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-12'></div>

<div class='col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-12'></div>
<div class='col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-12'></div>
<div class='col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-12'></div>
<div class='col-md-1 col-sm-3 col-xs-12'></div>

   </div>
</div>
```